# Allow user to click in DataGridViewImageCell but not change the existing row selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following `DataGridView` the first two columns are `DataGridViewImageCell`.

[image]

What I'm wondering is I would like the user to be able to click on the first cell (with the plus sign) and run through it's click method, but not change the currently Selected rows.

I don't want anything to happen if the clicks on the second column, no click event no selection change.

At the moment I've just got the click event running through `CellContentClick`.

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridViewEx dgvGeometryAudit = (DataGridViewEx)sender;
        //Test for first column name IMAGE_TOGGLE
        if (dgvGeometryAudit.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("IMAGE_TOGGLE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            ASSET_HEADER ah = (ASSET_HEADER)dgvGeometryAudit.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;

            ExpandRow(dgvGeometryAudit, ah, e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: i do not know if there is built in method or some fast way but if you do not find anything what came to my mind to do is store all selected rows to list after they are selected (index), and if user click on first or second column, you just do the job, deselect all and then select what is inside of list

Comment: It's not the most elegant, but it is a solution! Stick it in an answer @AleksaRistic

Comment: Will wait if someone answer something else

Comment: Can you change the SelectionMode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create global variable `private List<int> selectedRows = new List<int>()` and then inside `cellClick` event use this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.ColumnIndex != 1)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected == false)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            selectedRows.Add(e.RowIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = false;
            selectedRows.Remove(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        //Do your job here for that column/row
        foreach(int r in selectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[r].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will prevent the unwanted selection to happen in the first place. You may want to change it a to default to your normal selection mode..:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, 
                                         DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = e.ColumnIndex == yourImageColumIndex ?
                  DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect : 
                  DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;    // or whatever you want
}
```